# CSS overflow extension oddity

Tags: css, overflow

Using CSS we have a panel with overflow:auto. For some unknown reason the panel that contains the scrolling elements is nearly twice as big as it should be. The panel uses ajax to load in more content and no matter how big the scrollable div needs to be it doubles in size.

WHY http://jsfiddle.net/MnWNt/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is being caused by `#coursepack .dircore a .tit` having a `height` of `100%`.

Removing this height solves your problem.

Here's a [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MnWNt/4/).

Comment: Glad to have helped. If you don't already, you might want to look into FireBug for Firefox. It'll help you track these kinds of problems by being able to inspect the elements you're having problems with.